# Search Query not providing desired result?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have this code as :

```
   DBManager *db = [[DBManager alloc] initWithPath:DB_NAME];
    if(sites) {
        [sites release];
        sites = nil;
    }
    NSString *q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AND site.name LIKE \"%%%@%%\" LIMIT %d", filterQuery, self.searchString, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS];
    sites = [[db smartQueryForArrayWithStatement:q] retain];
    [db release];
    siteLoading = NO;

    if(self.filterApplied) {
        NSLog(@"filterApplied");
    }
    [self.tablView reloadData];
}
```

[image]

But I get this output.
But it should return me `NULL VALUE`( ie. NO LOCATION Or Any other similar search result matching to the search query entered).

Do i need to change My DB query to get the exact result ? If somebody can tell me what change I need to make because for other all search results I am getting the desired results except Perth, Queensland, dalby which give me wrong result as shown in the image.

Comment: try to "NSLOG" your searchString just before [db release].. maybe you are searching just "pert"; I had something similar… :)

Comment: I don't see the part of your question that concerns Xcode. --> Removing abused tag.